# Cobalt - Can't hide the UI when there are css animations on the page

Tags: animation, cobalt

My HTML/CSS/Js code is as follows:

```js
let con = document.getElementById("container")
setTimeout(function(){
    // while(con.hasChildNodes){
    //     con.removeChild(con.firstChild)
    // }
    con.style.display = "none"
},3 * 1000)
```

```css
#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    background: #00ff00
}
.item{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ff00ff;
    animation: move 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes move{
    0%{
        transform: translateX(100px)
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(200px)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>page not refresh</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome or firefox, the UI can be hidden 3 seconds later.
In Cobalt, the UI can't be hidden 3 seconds later.

If we remove the animation from the css file in Cobalt, the UI can be hidden 3 seconds later successfully.

How to hide the UI when there is animation on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt renders only necessary area. If there is nothing to render, it does not do anything. In your case, there is no specified background color so there is nothing to update after hiding the item. 
Setting the background color should fix the problem, as it means there is something to render - which is 'white' color - after hiding the item.

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Setting background-color to body can hide div elements, but the video layer will be covered by the background color, white for example. What we need is to completely hide all HTML contents when necessary -- just like youtube app. I think cobalt should support this because youtube can works fine in this scenario. Could you please guide me how to handle this case?

Comment: background-color is used to set the default pixel when there is no other things to render over it. If there is anything to draw, it shouldn't be covered by the background color. YouTube app works fine on Cobalt in that regards. If you still have problems, can you please share your code?

Comment: The bounds of the video tag should punch through any graphics rendered behind the video element, so it shouldn't matter if there is a background color or image, or even other elements behind the video element.

Comment: Frank, are you trying to compose Cobalt on top of other apps? In that case you might want `body` to have `transparent` background.

Comment: In our system, the video content is played by Mstar and on the layer 0. The cobalt browser is on the layer 1. The cobalt browser is on top of the video content. So the background of cobalt has to be transparent. I found the following answer to the question "Can cobalt support transparent background" which were posted by Andrew Top: "In cobalt/renderer/pipeline.cc,

If you add:
rasterizer_options.flags = rasterizer::Rasterizer::kSubmitFlags_Clear;
."  After I used this change, my problem is resolved.

Comment: Hi Frank, does David's comment address your issue?  You should just place your video element as usual and do not concern yourself with making the background transparent.  Cobalt will punch through the video element bounding box (possibly the whole screen) so that whatever is behind it (e.g. layer 0) becomes visible.